# How to get variables from all hosts in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to get an array of values of the specific variable from all hosts. For example: let's say I have host `dc1.com` with variable `test_var = "value1"` and host `dc2.com` with variable `test_var = "value2"`. I want to get an array of these values that looks like this `[ "value1", "value2" ]`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch any existing var from any available host through the [`hostvars` dict available as a magic var](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables)

e.g.:

```yaml
hostvars["dc1.com"].test_var
```

If you want a list of all found values, the following will go through all hosts in your inventory and extract the defined values in a list. Check the documentation on [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) for more details and to arrange to your exact requirements.

```yaml
- name: Show a list of all test_var values in my inventory
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars | dict2items | selectattr('value.test_var', 'defined') | map(attribute='value.test_var') }}"
```

Bonus (once more study the documentation above for more explanation), almost the same as above but only for your two example hosts. Note I dropped the attribute defined filter taking for granted the var will exist.

```yaml
- name: Show list of test_var valuse for dc1 and dc2 hosts
  vars:
    host_list:
      - dc1.com
      - dc2.com
  debug:
    msg: "{{ host_lists | map('extract', hostvars) | map(attribute='test_var') }}"
```